# Download shell file with wget

Tags: linux, shell, download, wget

I am trying to download the shell file with the wget tool. When I am trying to download the particular **.sh** file, the file named **.sh** is getting downloaded, but the content shown in the file is the **HTML**, not the actual file content. Hence it is downloading the **HTML** page provided as an input. The scenarios are as follows

**wget command**

```
wget --user=username --password=password https://some_url/Required_shell.sh -P /root/Desktop/
```

When I directly copy the URL used in wget in the browser, it downloads the file, but same case not happens with wget tool.

**URL pasted in browser**

```
https://some_url/Required_shell.sh
```

**Output with wget tool**

> Required_shell.sh with HTML content, not the required shell file.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites can disallow you to download its page by identifying that the user agent is not a browser. So you can mask the user agent by using **–user-agent** options and show wget like a browser as shown below.

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12" https://URL/TO/DOWNLOAD
```

Comment: I tried the same with following input but no luck. :(. wget --user=username --password=passwd --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" http://url/to/download/file/ShellFile.sh